# How to sum up values of duplicate keys in a dictionary?

Tags: c#

I have 5 columns in a spreadsheet (DevExpress spreadsheet). The first four columns are string values. The fifth column is integer (numeric). I joined those first four columns and put it as KEYs in a list, then collected the fifth column entries as VALUEs in an another list. I used these two lists to create a dictionary.
Now, I want to sum values related to each duplicate keys. As you now, dictionary object throw an exception for duplicate keys and remove related duplicate keys (keep unique keys). How can I sum those values related to each duplicate keys?
I tried this:

```
{
        IWorkbook workbook = spreadsheetControl.Document;
        Worksheet worksheet = workbook.Worksheets.ActiveWorksheet;
        CellRange range = worksheet.GetDataRange();
        int LastRow = range.BottomRowIndex;
        var keys = new List<string>();
        var values = new List<int>();

        for (int i = 0; i < LastRow + 1; i++)
        {
            keys.Add(string.Join(",", worksheet.Cells[i, 0].DisplayText, worksheet.Cells[i, 1].DisplayText,
                worksheet.Cells[i, 2].DisplayText, worksheet.Cells[i, 3].DisplayText));
            values.Add((int)worksheet.Cells[i, 4].Value.NumericValue);
        }
        var mydic = new Dictionary<string, int>();
        for (int i = 0; i < keys.Count; i++)
        {
            try
            {
                mydic.Add(keys[i], values[i]);
            }
            catch (Exception)
            {
                
            }
        }
    }
```

Comment: I don't feel like writing a full answers so let me just descibe the process. 1. The data should be in an Array since dictionaries cannot have duplicates.   `array.GroupBy(x => x.Key).ToDictionary(x => x.Key, v => v.ToArray()).`  Now you'll have a key with all the values, you can either take the first one and assume all the values are the same or instead if the values differ create new keys for them etc

Comment: Just use dictionary in the first "for". check if the key exists. add key if necessary. then pull the existing value via key, sum it with new value then update the existing value via key.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to check for key existence first. If the key already exists, you add the value directly rather than call the `Add()` method.

```
    var mydic = new Dictionary<string, int>();
    for (int i = 0; i < keys.Count; i++)
    {
        if(mydic.ContainsKey(keys[i]))
            mydic[keys[i]] += values[i];
        else
            mydic.Add(keys[i], values[i]);
    }
```

Comment: This aggregates the values in the OP's original code they ignore the value if its not the first

Comment: The original code doesn't do sum anyway, while the question description says sum is the intention. `Now, I want to sum values related to each duplicate keys.`

Answer (score 3):

Use the dictionary already in the first `for`-loop with `TryGetValue`:

```
var myDictionary = new Dictionary<string, int>();
for (int i = 0; i < LastRow + 1; i++)
{
    string key = string.Join(",", worksheet.Cells[i, 0].DisplayText, worksheet.Cells[i, 1].DisplayText, worksheet.Cells[i, 2].DisplayText, worksheet.Cells[i, 3].DisplayText);
    int value = (int)worksheet.Cells[i, 4].Value.NumericValue;
    if(myDictionary.TryGetValue(key, out int oldValue)) 
        value += oldValue;
    myDictionary[key] = value;
}
```

The setter of the [dictionary indexer](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.collections.generic.dictionary-2.item?view=net-5.0) never throws an exception if the key does not exist as opposed to the [`Add` method](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.collections.generic.dictionary-2.add?view=net-5.0). If it exists it will replace the old value with the new.